# How to format the negative values in dataflow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have below column in my table

[image]

I need an output as below

[image]

I am using Dataflow in the Azure data factory and unable to get the above output. I used derived column but no success. I used replace function, but it's not coming correct. Can anyone advise how to format this in dataflow?

Comment: Give the expression as `iif(left(id,1)=='-', replace(replace(id,"USD",""),"-","-$"), concat("$", replace(id,"USD","")))`  in derived column transformation

Comment: You work with `Beam` `Python` or `Java` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Source is taken in data flow with data as in below image.

[image]

- Derived column transformation is added next to source.
- New column is added and the expression is given as
  `iif(left(id,1)=='-', replace(replace(id,"USD",""),"-","-$"), concat("$", replace(id,"USD","")))`
  [image]

**Output of Derived Column activity**

[image]